# Drools DRL Export to Java and Python

Tags: java, drools

There is requirement to convert Drools DRL file into equivalent Java and Python Code as a Export Feature. Please provide some insights whether any tools available for this. Or we can use DRL Debug Dump can be used to export Java equivalent code. Please share your suggestions and inputs.

Comment: Asking for tool suggestions is off-topic for stackoverflow, so you might want to do some re-wording so this doesn't get closed as off-topic.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the rationale of this. Why transform DRL in Java when you can call this DRL with Java code to execute it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java equivalent code for a DRL. The DRL is processed in a way that generates a graph of nodes (based on the RETE algorithm) that are evaluated when information is made available to a session.
If you were expecting to get some Java classes with a bunch of `if-else` statements, then you are out of luck.

There are ways to export the RETE Graph if you want to, but I'm sure that's not what you are looking for.